# File Upload not working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So i had to write some python code and i started working in google colab , now the requirement has been specified to Jupyter Notebooks

Before i was using simple files.upload() in google colab but for some reason it is not supported in jupyter notebooks , so i tried using their own function

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def file_upload():
    upload_btn = widgets.FileUpload()
    trigger_btn = widgets.Button(description="Upload File")
    display(upload_btn)
    display(trigger_btn)

uploaded_content = None

def on_upload_btn_click(change):
    nonlocal uploaded_content
    uploaded_content = list(upload_btn.value.values())[0].get('content', b'').decode('utf-8')
    print("File uploaded successfully!")

trigger_btn.on_click(on_upload_btn_click)

# Wait for the user to click the trigger button
print("Waiting for file upload...")
while uploaded_content is None:
    pass

return uploaded_content

def main():
    # Upload your_file.txt
    file_content = file_upload()

# Create a file-like object from the uploaded content
rectangles = parse_rectangles_from_file(io.StringIO(file_content))

# Extract maximum x and y values from the dataset so as to set the axes
max_x = max(rect[3] for rect in rectangles)  # Maximum right_top_corner_x
max_y = max(rect[4] for rect in rectangles)  # Maximum right_top_corner_y

# Create an R-tree index
p = rtree_index.Property()
rtree_idx = rtree_index.Index(properties=p)

# Batch insert into R-tree
batch_size = 2000  # Adjust the batch size based on your available memory
for i in range(0, len(rectangles), batch_size):
    batch = rectangles[i:i+batch_size]
    batch_insert_into_rtree(rtree_idx, batch)

# Plot the rectangles
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, max_x + (0.1*max_x))  # Set x-axis limit based on maximum x value
ax.set_ylim(0, max_y + (0.1*max_y))  # Set y-axis limit based on maximum y value

for index, set_of_numbers in enumerate(rectangles, start=1):
    rect_instance = RectangleDetails(*set_of_numbers)
    block_left_bottom = (rect_instance.lb_x, rect_instance.lb_y)
    size = [rect_instance.rt_x - rect_instance.lb_x,
            rect_instance.rt_y - rect_instance.lb_y]

    plot_rect(ax, block_left_bottom, size, index)

plt.show()

x = float(input("Enter x coordinate: "))
y = float(input("Enter y coordinate: "))
point = (x, y)
print("Naive")
%timeit -r 1 -o find_enclosing_rectangles_naive(point, rectangles)
enclosing_rectangles_naive = find_enclosing_rectangles_naive(point, rectangles)
enclosing_rectangles_naive.sort()

print("RTree")
%timeit -r 1 -o find_enclosing_rectangles_rtree(point, rtree_idx)
enclosing_rectangles_rtree = find_enclosing_rectangles_rtree(point, rtree_idx)
enclosing_rectangles_rtree.sort()

if enclosing_rectangles_naive:
    print(f"The point {point} is enclosed in the rectangles: {enclosing_rectangles_naive}")
else:
    print(f"The point {point} is not enclosed in any rectangle.")

if enclosing_rectangles_rtree:
    print(f"The point {point} is enclosed in the rectangles: {enclosing_rectangles_rtree}")
else:
    print(f"The point {point} is not enclosed in any rectangle.")

non_overlapping_ids = find_non_overlapping_rectangles_naive(rectangles)
print("Non-overlapping rectangles:", non_overlapping_ids)

%timeit -r 1 -o find_overlapping_rectangles(rectangles)
overlapping_rectangles = find_overlapping_rectangles(rectangles)
print("Overlapping rectangles:", overlapping_rectangles)

%timeit -r 1 -o find_overlapping_rectangles_rtree(rectangles, rtree_idx)
overlapping_rectangles_rtree = find_overlapping_rectangles_rtree(rectangles, rtree_idx)
print("Overlapping rectangles with R-tree:", overlapping_rectangles_rtree)

%timeit -r 1 -o find_containing_rectangles(rectangles)
containing_rectangles = find_containing_rectangles(rectangles)
print("List of rectangles enclosing other rectangles ",containing_rectangles)


%timeit -r 1 -o find_abutting_rectangles(rectangles)
abutting_rect=find_abutting_rectangles(rectangles);
print(abutting_rect)


# Run the main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After uploading the file and clicking the uplaod button , nothing happens , it stays right there saying Waiting for file upload...

I tried looking for possible errors but all i could find is something related to upload_btn.value.values() , tuple not having value attribute

Comment: You seem to need a file object for `rectangles = parse_rectangles_from_file()` and so I'm not seeing why you aren't just writing the uploaded content as a file so that you can track it working better than you are doing now. Plus, I think you need to nest your code in indented sections more than you are doing now. You have to observe the change after uploading and then only then doing the subsequent stuff. Don't combing use of `input()` with ipywidgets observving because it will block things, I believe; `input()` is a rudimentary way to interact leftover from legacy stuff and not compatible ...

Comment: <continued> with ipywidgets. You don't need the `if __name__ == "__main__":` and `main()` stuff in the notebook code and it could be leading to problems. I have an example of uploading the content and saving it as a file that then can get used subsequently in the Jupyter `.ipynb` file code [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibADJUSTABLE.ipynb). Maybe that will point you to where your is giving you issues? If you want to try the code I reference that ...

Comment: <continued> includes the upload steps, go to [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#3dscatter_plot-binder) and then click 'launch binder' badge. When the session comes up, choose '3D scatter plot using data in a file and Voila interface' from the list of available demonstration notebooks. Run the code as a notebook as it says is an option in the pre-amble; disregard mentions of Voila.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because your code indefinitely waits for `upload_content` to change its state. This type of action is not supported by Jupyter.

You can simply

```
def file_upload():
    upload_btn = widgets.FileUpload(accept='', multiple=False)
    display(upload_btn)

    def on_upload_btn_click(change):
        uploaded_file = next(iter(upload_btn.value.values()))
        content = uploaded_file['content']
        print("File uploaded successfully!"
        return content
    upload_btn.observe(on_upload_btn_click, names='value')
    return on_upload_btn_click
```

For using it simply:

```
conten = file_upload()
```

Comment: but then how do I later use the file uploaded since the function isn't returning anything , i need to use it for my further calculations

Comment: @chetxn04 try  now just added 2 return statement that should work